# How to only trigger one onClick function when inside a component also with onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the sample code....

```
<div onClick={this.handeAAAClick}>
  <img onClick={this.handleLinkClick}/>
</div>
```

When I click the div and it will trigger handleAAAClick event, however, when I only click on img, and it will trigger both click event, what I want is only to trigger handleLinkClick.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `handleLinkClick` will get a parameter `event`.On this parameter there is a `stopPropagation` method.You need to call it.

```
function handleLinkClick(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```